# Search by array of values in .select query method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having this type of search:

```
values = ModelName.find(:all, :conditions => ['attr_id IN (SELECT attr_id FROM srv_type_attr WHERE id IN (?))', serv_objt_attr.collect(&:stya_id)])
```

Witch returns me an array of needed values:

```
[33458, 33438]
```

Next i need to check if record exists with `select`:

```
serv_objt_attr.select {|array| array.stya_id == values.collect(&:attr_id).uniq}
```

This is an example what i'm thinking off.

So how to do it with select, so he would walk through all values witch i'm getting from `values`.

I know that i could to something like

```
values.collect(&:attr_id).uniq do |val|
serv_objt_attr.select {|array| array.stya_id == val}
end
```

But i do not thing that this is a good option.

Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.4

Comment: May I ask what Rails version you are using? Because `Model.find(:all, :conditions => [...])` isn't a statement you come across often. Normally you'd use `Model.where(...)` This might be relevant for those writing answers.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Added rails version.

Comment: When looking at the first two code blocks I'd assume `values` is an array containing integers. I'm a bit confused by your third and fourth code block, especially `values.collect(&:attr_id)` which is short for `values.collect { |value| value.attr_id }`. An integer doesn't have the method `attr_id` as far as I know. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case for the set intersection operator:

```
values = ModelName.find(:all, :conditions => ['attr_id IN (SELECT attr_id FROM srv_type_attr WHERE id IN (?))', serv_objt_attr.collect(&:stya_id)])

values & Set.new(serv_objt_attr.map(&:stya_id)
```

Here's what the [&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26) does:

```
>> values = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> other_array = [1,5,9,3]
=> [1, 5, 9, 3]
>> values & other_array
=> [1, 3]
```